# Cut NSString to carriage return

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, cut

I have NSString example:

```
@"Hello, Hello

How are you?"
```

I need to keep them words to transfer carriage. That is @"Hello, Hello"

I have text from UIWebView.
Text I get

```
NSString *myText = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
    NSLog(@"my text -> %@",myText);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander, if I'm reading this right, you want to cut string before new line symbol comes.

eg.
**Before:**"Hello
World"
**After:**"Hello"

If so you can use this NSString category:

**NSString+CutToNewLine.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (CutToNewLine)
- (NSString *)cutToNewLine;
@end
```

**NSString+CutToNewLine.m**

```
#import "NSString+CutToNewLine.h"


@implementation NSString (CutToNewLine)
- (NSString *)cutToNewLine
{
    NSRange newLineRange = [self rangeOfString: @"\n"];
    NSRange stringBeforeNewLineRange = NSMakeRange(0, newLineRange.location);

    NSString *resultString = [self substringWithRange: stringBeforeNewLineRange];

    return resultString;
}

@end
```

**Results**

```
 NSString *s = @"Hello\nWorld!";
 NSLog(@"%@", s);
 NSLog(@"%@", [s cutToNewLine]);
```

***Output***

```
2013-03-04 20:02:17.075 NSStringCut[734:f07] Hello
World!
2013-03-04 20:02:17.076 NSStringCut[734:f07] Hello

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Code sample you can find [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/930742/so/NSStringCut.zip)

BR
Eugene.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert `\n` to make a newline

```
@"Hello, Hello\n\nHow are you?"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use that
`@"Hello, Hello\n\n\rHow are you?"`